# Not getting push notification on Android 12 in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin.forms, push-notification, onesignal

I have developed iOS and Android app using Xamarin.Forms.

I have implemented Push notification for my app using FCM and OneSignal.
For apps running on below Android 12, Push notification is working fine.

For Android 12 and higher there is crash while getting push notification.

I have nuget package installed for Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging (71.1740.1) and Com.OneSignal(3.8.4).

Below are services used for FCM and com.OneSignal.

```
[Service(Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT", "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]

[Service(Exported = true, Name = "com.company.project.OneSignalNotificationExtenderService", Permission = "android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.onesignal.NotificationExtender" })]
```

For Android 12 and higher there is crash while getting push notification with below is stack trace -

```
--- End of managed Java.Lang.RuntimeException stack trace ---
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:415)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.company.projectname: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:645)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:632)
at com.onesignal.GenerateNotification.getNewActionPendingIntent(GenerateNotification.java:189)
at com.onesignal.GenerateNotification.createGenericPendingIntentsForNotif(GenerateNotification.java:398)
at com.onesignal.GenerateNotification.showNotification(GenerateNotification.java:382)
at com.onesignal.GenerateNotification.fromJsonPayload(GenerateNotification.java:110)
at com.onesignal.NotificationBundleProcessor.ProcessJobForDisplay(NotificationBundleProcessor.java:107)
at com.onesignal.NotificationExtenderService.processJsonObject(NotificationExtenderService.java:202)
at com.onesignal.NotificationExtenderService.processIntent(NotificationExtenderService.java:155)
at com.onesignal.NotificationExtenderService.onHandleWork(NotificationExtenderService.java:123)
at com.onesignal.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:439)
at com.onesignal.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:430)
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
... 3 more
```

After RND, I have updated pending intent flag then also there is crash.

```
var pendingIntentFlags = (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.S)
            ? PendingIntentFlags.Immutable
            : PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent;
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 1200 + result.Payload.ActionButtons.IndexOf(item), intent, pendingIntentFlags);
```

I found we have to update Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging for Android 12.
Then I have updated Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging nuget package to latest version (123.1.2.2).
After updation, there is a method to set device token.

```
public void SetDeviceToken(object token)
    {
        deviceToken = (string)token;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(deviceToken))
        {
    //deviceToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;

            var id = FirebaseInstallations.Instance.GetId();
            deviceToken = id.ToString();

         //   deviceToken = FirebaseMessaging.Instance.GetToken().ToString();
        }
            

        if (this.chatClient != null && deviceToken != null)
        {
            Logger.Info("ChatClient", "ChatClientCallbackListener: FCM token: " + deviceToken);
            this.chatClient.RegisterFCMToken(new ChatClient.FCMToken((string)deviceToken), new StatusListeners.RegisterFCMTokenStatusListener());
            tokenRegistered = true;
        }
    }
```

Getting error for FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token - FirebaseInstanceId does not exist in current context.
So I got some solutions to get token for this so I have tried to add

```
var id = FirebaseInstallations.Instance.GetId();
            deviceToken = id.ToString();
```

There is no crash but not getting notification.
Also I tried to add

```
deviceToken = FirebaseMessaging.Instance.GetToken().ToString();
```

We already getting device token so it will not go inside if condition.

I have tried to make exported value false for both services still not working.

There is no crash but not getting notification.  Is it because of below error?

For both the things app build successfully but getting error-

```
Unknown error getting FCM Token
[OneSignal] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId;
[OneSignal]     at com.onesignal.PushRegistratorFCM.getToken(PushRegistratorFCM.java:94)
[OneSignal]     at com.onesignal.PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.attemptRegistration(PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.java:97)
[OneSignal]     at com.onesignal.PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.access$100(PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.java:37)
[OneSignal]     at com.onesignal.PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle$1.run(PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.java:84)
[OneSignal]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
[OneSignal] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class `"com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId" on path: DexPathList[[zip file` `"com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~clH8Z-xJFqbWR_JeEWSUuQ==/com.company.projectname-_UpkPkjlCAH_1fCi-G2cXQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~clH8Z-xJFqbWR_JeEWSUuQ==/com.company.projectname-_UpkPkjlCAH_1fCi-G2cXQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~clH8Z-xJFqbWR_JeEWSUuQ==/com.company.projectname-_UpkPkjlCAH_1fCi-G2cXQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]`
[OneSignal]     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
[OneSignal]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
[OneSignal]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
```

So I have updated com.OneSignal to 3.10.4 version.
After upgradation of com.OneSignal there is below error-

android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#com.onesignal.NotificationOpenedActivityHMS>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined.

So I have added below code in manifest file.

```
<activity android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpenedActivityHMS" android:exported="true"></activity>
```

Still not getting notification and no badge count on app icon .

I am doing RND on this. I am little confused for this notification process that I am going in right direction or not for not getting notification.

Versions for nuget package installed for Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging (123.1.2.2) and Com.OneSignal(3.10.4).

Is there issue with versions? Or if you think something is missing or need to do any changes then please help me out.

Comment: `FirebaseMessaging.Instance.GetToken()` is an async method. To get a result you need to use `token = (string)await FirebaseMessaging.Instance.GetToken();` . Also, did you put the google-services.json file in your project ?

Comment: @Bibimission, I have added google-services.json file. Issue is on Android 12 and higher devices.  I have tried above code by adding await but still not getting notification.

Comment: Do you have this in your AndroidManifest.xml file ?  
<receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
 <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
  <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
  <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
 </intent-filter>
</receiver>

Comment: Inside this receiver I do not have registration and category.  <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

Comment: Inside <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

Comment: As I mentioned in question, we already getting device token so it will not go inside if condition to call deviceToken = FirebaseMessaging.Instance.GetToken().ToString();

Comment: Try to Install Xamarin.Firebase.Iid nuget and Xamarin.GooglePlayService.Base

Comment: I have installed above mentioned nuget package. Now getting app crash with 1st error mentioned in question. Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.tranquility.liberate: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.       Even I have added code for this.

Comment: This is an issue on the Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging You can follow up this [issue thread](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/761) on the GitHub issue.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT Thanks. I will check above mentioned thread.

Answer (score 0):

The service should look something like this:

```cs
[Service(Name = "full.dotnet.namespace.in.lowercase.except.for.className.FirebasePushMessagingService", Exported = false)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class FirebasePushMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        base.OnMessageReceived(message);
        // Put a breakpoint here to verify receipt of push notification.
    }

    public override void OnNewToken(string token)
    {
        base.OnNewToken(token);
        // Send to server using WorkManager
    }
}
```

Note: the token you would use to send a notification to this device is provided to you in the newer `OnNewToken` method.

You also need to setup some stuff in the Android manifest (if you aren't setting these in the actual push notification). These settings control the default icon, color, channel, etc. of the notification. Note the meta-data tags.

```xml
    <application>
        <!-- Firebase Cloud Messaging settings -->
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/notification_route" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" android:resource="@color/notification_color" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" android:value="@string/route_notification_channel_id" />
    </application>
```

This is working for me without OneSignal. I would suggest trying to receive a push notification without OneSignal first to see if the problem exists there or in your FCM implementation.

Comment: since Android 12, do we need to add this metadata for notification icon,color? Because I am getting notifications on Android devices having OS below 12.

Comment: If you don't include the metadata in your app then it needs to be included in each outgoing Firebase message. In my case, I set it in the app manifest because I'm just using one channel, icon, and color. See the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) under the "Android — keys for notification messages" heading.

Comment: I am quite confused here between Android 12 and below 12 push notifications. Because On Android 11, I am getting notification with icons and everything. Even on Android 12 I am getting notification. Only the thing is I am not able to see it in this method in App.xaml  - private void AppNotificationReceived(OSNotification notification). Only it will not show on Notification center and there is no badge count